# How to deliver large volumes of help content for a managed package?

Tags: knowledge, content, help

We have been using ZIP static resources included in our managed packages for help content. These are exported from [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) and linked into our managed packages via Visualforce pages (so that `$Resource` can be used to reference the static resources).

We now have a lot more content that we want to make available, so the 5M limit on a static resource is a problem as is the 250M limit on the total size of all static resources.

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to handle this better. My assumption is that the content will need to move to an external system, be that some 3rd party product or perhaps a Salesforce Community. Looking for good authoring tools and easy publishing. Multiple versions of the information will need to be supported correspdonding to the multiple managed package versions. Any recommendations?

Ideally this content will only be accessible to Salesforce users (various single sign on mechanisms can handle that) who have a license for one of our products (much harder to achieve). Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for moving the content to a hosted solution. It reduces the burden of including the content with your managed package and ensures the latest copies can be referenced by customers without having to wait on their managed package being upgraded.

For my hobby projects, I've started including links to my GitHub README or wiki that hosts a living FAQ.

Comment: I was kind of thinking the reverse. With Static Resources the help content would always correspond to the version it was released with. Pluses and minuses...

Comment: I would do it just like Salesforce Release Notes; have each version out there. Especially if customers don't all upgrade at same time. You at least have one spot to worry about publishing docs than include in managed package pushed to each customer, especially if SIZE is a concern.

Comment: Which makes me wonder what drives the Salesforce Docs themselves? API version selection is one of the things they do well.

Comment: Doug, yeah, wondering if anyone has come across a good authoring tools and a good way to publish; we are talking about hundreds of pages and lots of screenshots. And as Daniel mentions versioning. And securing the content...

Comment: Have you considered Confluence?

Comment: Do you mean to publish? (We already author in Confluence.) The problem is that Confluence's OAUTH2 support isn't there.

Comment: yeah, was just curious why you weren't just leveraging your own content management system.